# New Show instance for existing type

Tags: purescript

I have wrapper type for NonEmptyList of my custom type `Cell`:

```
instance Show Cell where
  show = ...

type CellsRow = NonEmptyList Cell
```

I trying to create `Show` instance for `Cells` as well with:

```
instance Show CellsRow where
  show = foldMap show
```

But it raises `Orphan instance found for ...`. I can resolve it by making `CellsRow` newtype, but can I use both `Show` instance and simple `type CellsRow = NonEmptyList Cell`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot declare multiple instances for the same type. This is on purpose, otherwise there would be ambiguity in instance resolution.

The error refers to a subset of this - what is called "orphan" instances. These are such instances that neither the class definition nor the type definition are in the same module. In PureScript you can only declare instances either in the same module as the type or in the same module as the class.

Comment: So, my type alias for NonEmptyList doesn't count as new type?

Comment: @MaxSmirnov no, a type alias is literally just that, an alias - another name for an existing type. The two names are completely interchangeable, and there is only one type here.